# Why am I getting CD requests in Debian APT-GET?

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt, data-cd

Code and outputs

```
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs
[sudo] password for masi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreadline5
Suggested packages:
  xfsdump attr quota
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreadline5 xfsprogs
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/853 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,963 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20150606-15:28'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

where the last row indicates the request of CD. 
This is the second time today. 
I installed `apt-file` to my system and put `sbin` to my PATH after which this has occurred.

I think this may be a problem with sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
I run `sudo apt-get update` but it does not solve the problem, as described [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=75238).

### No support of XFS in Debian?

I am following this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/367077/1944) and I type

```
mkfs.x[tab]
mkfs.bfs      mkfs.ext3     mkfs.fat      mkfs.minix    mkfs.vfat
mkfs.cramfs   mkfs.ext4     mkfs.hfs      mkfs.msdos    
mkfs.ext2     mkfs.ext4dev  mkfs.hfsplus  mkfs.ntfs
```

so this insertion of CD seems to be Debian's way of saying NO.

Why is Debian 8.1 asking for the installation media requests in Debian apt-get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete or comment (`#`) the cdrom line(s) in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and look at files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and run

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: Is everything that is available in CDs available in network?

Comment: Yes, you will find everything and up to date on the mirrors.